# How can I make this GIF appear correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, gif, zposition

I created a GIF and it is basically snow particles falling and has a transparent background. Therefore I can have just snow flowing over my other PNGs and images on the app. The problem is that the app loads and the GIF appears all white. Not sure why because I gave it transparency when making it. If I lower the alpha in Xcode I still don't see my old PNGs (usual background image).

This is in my ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"snow" ofType:@"gif"];
  NSData *gif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

  UIWebView *webViewBG = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
  [webViewBG loadData:gif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
  webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  [self.view addSubview:webViewBG];

  UIView *filter = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
  //filter.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  filter.alpha = 0.5;
  [self.view addSubview:filter];
```

Comment: set the webviews background to clear color? also not sure if the content of the webview will be transparent... you can make UIImageViews with animated images afaik, you have to give it an array of images though not a gif i think

Answer (score 1):

You can set your view background Clear color And for animated image you can use UIImageView.
hope this will be work proper.
See Link:: - [Click here to get code](https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone)
Link2::- [Click here for code](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)